# Angular 2 this.generateTree is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have 2 functions in my component. onElementClick is binded to element in HTML. So every time I click on that element, I get:

> this.showHalo is not a function

Why is this a case?

```
showHalo(view, opt) {
  // Code
}

 onElementClick(view) {
 // Code
  function click() {
    this.showHalo(view, { animation: true });
  }
}
```

I even tried this, but its the same thing.

```
myFunc(){
   console.log("TEST");
}

onElementClick(view) {
   self = this;
   self.myFunc();
}
```

Comment: share HTML too.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485 your `this` is not refering to your component inside that functions scope.

Comment: In your updated question section, you don't even need to preserve `this`, it should work like simple call `myFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `this` pointer. Like :

```
showHalo(view, opt) {
  // Code
}

 onElementClick(view) {
 // Code
var _this = this;
  function click() {
    _this.showHalo(view, { animation: true });
  }
}
```

Comment: @masterfan : In your updated question section, you don't even need to preserve `this`, it should work like simple call `myFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

this object will not be available in local function scope. You need to assign this to local scope variable and use it in click function.

```
  showHalo() {
  console.log('hihih')
  }

  onElementClick() {
    console.log('2323');
    var self = this;
    click();
    function click(){
      self.showHalo();
    }
```

Comment: That should not be the pbm..Have you tried above code?

Comment: Share HTML part too from where you are calling onElementClick function